# ReactJS - onClick to call a component that fadeIn

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

New web dev I found some nice pure HTML/JQuery template.

https://www.creative-tim.com/

I have to do an app with React and I would like to implement to login modal template on this web site.

https://www.creative-tim.com/product/login-and-register-modal

I'm not sure about the approch I have to make to be able to convert this to React.

I have to handle the `onClick` on the buttons and make the modal appear.
How can I load the component `Modal` by change the CSS like the way they do with JQuery ?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Grid, Row, Col, Button } from 'react-bootstrap/lib'
import './Login.css'

import LoginModal from '../LoginModal/LoginModal'

class Login extends Component {

  openLoginModal(){
    console.log('openLoginModal');
    // showLoginForm();
  }

  openRegisterModal(){
    console.log('openRegisterModal');
    // showRegisterForm();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Grid>
        <Row>
          <Col sm={4}></Col>
          <Col sm={4}>
            <Button bsClass="btn big-login" data-toggle="modal" onClick={this.openLoginModal}>Log In</Button>
            <Button bsClass="btn big-register" data-toggle="modal" onClick={this.openRegisterModal}>Register</Button>
          </Col>
          <Col sm={4}></Col>
        </Row>
        <LoginModal />
      </Grid>
    )
  }
}

export default Login
```

Comment: Should be fairly easy by adding a class to your LoginModal component...  
E.g. pass props (e.g. visible & login state (register|login)) to LoginModal, depending on it set a class and render register or login inside modal & do some css magic -> overlay + show modal

Comment: It is css more than js. it depends on How are you adding the modal to your DOM.

Comment: You can look here : https://www.creative-tim.com/product/login-and-register-modal

I try to implement this but they are using JQuery to change the state. I dunno what is bugging me but I can't figure it out how to do it with React. Like I say Im very new to React.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In React you don't need to use CSS to show and hide the modal. You can just use an inline conditional expression with JSX.

first you need to build a RegisterModal...

...Then

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Grid, Row, Col, Button } from 'react-bootstrap/lib'
import './Login.css'

import LoginModal from '../LoginModal/LoginModal'
import RegisterModal from '../RegisterModal/RegisterModal';

class Login extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    // create state properties to record open/close for each modal
    this.state = {
      loginOpen: false,
      registerOpen: false
    };
  }
  // toggle your state 
  openLoginModal(){
    this.setState({ loginOpen: true, registerOpen: false });
  }

  openRegisterModal(){
    this.setState({ loginOpen: false, registerOpen: true  });
  }

  render() {
    // `{ true && <div /> }` will render div if true
    return (
      <Grid>
        <Row>
          <Col sm={4}></Col>
          <Col sm={4}>
            <Button bsClass="btn big-login" data-toggle="modal" onClick={this.openLoginModal}>Log In</Button>
            <Button bsClass="btn big-register" data-toggle="modal" onClick={this.openRegisterModal}>Register</Button>
          </Col>
          <Col sm={4}></Col>
        </Row>
        { this.state.loginOpen &&
          <LoginModal />
        }
        { this.state.registerOpen &&
          <RegisterModal />
        }
      </Grid>
    )
  }
}
```